# swift ios should I use core data or array/struct

Tags: ios, core-data

I wonder how I should receive data in my app.

Right now I have a relational sql file that I took form my server/backend.

Its a two tables state/cities that is relational one-to-many

In one table I have around 30 states
In table two I have around 250 states.

Is the best solution to save it in core data or in a array/struct?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be to convert it to JSON in your backend. And then in your App use `NSJSONSerialization` and convert it to `NSDictionary`. Then you can save the dictionary to a file and load and use it on demand.

Comment: I can make my backend output it as json. But will it note be slow/take alot of memory when reading from file?

Comment: Since the data is fairly small it will have a low memory footprint, and as for speed you will only need to load it once from the file into a dictionary and you can use it later on from the memory, so it won't be slow.